# How to manually handle clicks on chart elements like legend, bars, etc?

Tags: apexcharts

For example I have a bar chart. I want to show some detailed info per element (bar) when user clicks on it or its title in legend. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've found deeply hidden `chart.events` options that is partially suits my needs. For anyone interesting: https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/chart/events/

Answer (score 0):

you can use toolTip object with its properties.

Example given below.

```
var  chart =  new  CanvasJS.Chart("container",
{
 .
 .
 toolTip:{  
  // toolTip properties
  .
  .
 },
 .
 . 
});
chart.render();
```

Comment: CanvasJS is not Apexcharts